# Deserialising JSON into MVC Model

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller, json.net

In my MVC application I call a web service which provides some information in a JSON string.

```
[{"createdDate":"28/04/2019 09:55:54","round":"T4","colType":"7","colCount":"2","Day":"0001000"}]
```

In my application I have a model with the same properties as this string.

```
public class TWCollections
{
    public string createdDate { get; set; }
    public string round { get; set; }
    public string colType { get; set; }
    public string colCount { get; set; }
    public string Day { get; set; }
}
```

I originally tried Deserializing the JSON into this model, until I realised I would likely have more than one result, so I created the following...

```
public class accountCollections
{
        public List<TWCollections> cols { get; set; }
}
```

In my code I tried Deserializing the JSON Object into the model using the following code:

```
accountCollections collectionsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<accountCollections>(jsonString));
```

However I get the error...

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'Waste.Models.accountCollections' because the type requires a JSON
>   object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a
>   type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList)
>   like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
>   JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array.Path '', line 1, position 1.'

I tried adding the name from the JSON object above each property but this didn't work, which I figured as the names in my app are identical to the JSON string... As I say I also tried Deserializing to TWCollections as the example is a single result, but this also didn't work...

Thanks

Comment: can you provide complete JSON which you are deserializing?

Comment: I have provided it exactly as it is returned from the web service (above).. I have deserialized this to a var for testing purposes and can see the data is there.

Comment: you have `[...]` json array not `{"cols" : [...]}` json object ... so **obviously** you shoud deserialize it directly to list of your model class

Comment: we asking for `jsonString`

Comment: @sriharsha   the variable jsonString that is returned is.... [{"createdDate":"28/04/2019 09:55:54","round":"T4","colType":"7","colCount":"2","Day":"0001000"}]

Comment: Can u try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TWCollections>(jsonString))` this and check what error ur getting ?

Comment: Hi, I was getting the same error as previous. I fixed the issue by using IList

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed my own issue by using IList..

```
IList<TWCollections> collectionResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<TWCollections>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: You've fixed your own issue not by using an `IList` but by not deserializing to `accountCollections`

Comment: I explained in my original answer, I had tried both accountCollections and TWCollections previously but I have changed my accountCollections to reflect the IList so it works